# Why does .NET Core build generate an EXE file but not generate a dll file?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have .net core project, When i build that project it generates .exe file but not .dll, My requirement is to create .dll of project and host it in IIS server. how to generate .dll file,what settings need to be done.

Answer (score 3):

An ASP.Net Core binary is meant to be a self-hosted application, so the .exe embed a web server (the default one being Kestrel) that can accept HTTP requests. One of the challenges behind ASP.Net Core was to make it self-contained and decoupled from IIS. So having an .exe is perfectly expected, you can double click on it and you'll get a web server running.

That being said, in a standard production environment, you are supposed to have a webserver like IIS sitting in front of your ASP.Net Core app and acting as a reverse proxy, forwarding the requests to the app. So having an .exe file will not prevent you from hosting behind IIS.

I learned a lot from this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

If there is a way to create a DLL with ASP.Net Core, I don't know it, but what would be the point?

Comment: For an authoritative link: [Microsoft's documentation about the ASP.NET Core Module for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module), needed to host an ASP.NET Core app in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the output type in your project properties to Class Library from Console Application will generate a DLL instead of an EXE.